# Liferay dynamic jsp load by jQuery

Tags: liferay

I would like to dynamically load pages on liferay. Right now I do have jsp with renderURL and div:

```
<div id="sub_content2"></div>   

<portlet:renderURL var="displayOtherDocumentURL1">
<portlet:param name="action" value="displayOtherDocument" />
<portlet:param name="activeTab" value="2" />
<portlet:param name="activeVerticalTab" value="6" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<aui:script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert('1231');
    //$("#sub_content").load("displayEditSchoolEducation");
    //alert('11');
    $("#sub_conten2").load("${displayOtherDocumentURL1}");
        alert('aaa');
})
```

And in the controller I have this method:

```
  @RenderMapping(params = "action=displayOtherDocument")
public String displayOtherDocument(final RenderRequest request, final RenderResponse response,
        final ModelMap modelMap) throws PortalException, SystemException {}
```

Normally everything is working. But dynamically loading is not :( Help! Hilfe! Na pomoc!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="displayOtherDocumentURL" id="displayOtherDocument"></portlet:resourceURL>
```

--

```
$("#displayOtherDocumentDIV").load("${displayOtherDocumentURL}");
```

--

```
@ResourceMapping(value = "displayOtherDocument")
    public ModelAndView displayOtherDocument(final ResourceRequest request) throws PortalException, SystemException {

        final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("components/otherDocumentForm", model);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

easy, and working ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to load in ajax, you should create a ResourceMapping not a RenderMapping.

Comment: Still does`t work :( I tired it few hour ago. Problem is, that liferay does`t call spring requerst/resource mapping and i don`t know why :(

Comment: Can you show us the code you make with ResourceMapping ?

Comment: Ok. Maybe you can add your fixed to your answer for other users ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are missing the name of the jsp

```
<portlet:renderURL var="displayOtherDocumentURL1">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsp/new_page.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
```

then

```
$("#sub_conten2").load("${displayOtherDocumentURL1}");
```

Should work. if you would like to use resource instead which makes sense if you are not doing any jsp pre-process then you have to open the file and send the whole file.